# Problem with merging WARs using uberwar (cargo-maven2-plugin)

Tags: maven, cargo

I've just started using cargo-maven2-plugin to merge WAR artifacts during build process and I encountered problem with uberwar mojo.
Merging works fine but resulting web.xml file contains extra "xmlns" attributes that cause error when deploying on Jboss.

For example original context-param element looks like this:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and after merging it has extra "xmlns" attribute:

```
<context-param xmlns="">
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have found the following Jira issue but suggested solution is not clear to me:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/CARGO-639

Anybody faced similar problem and could share the solution?
If you use other tools (that work) to merge WARs please let me know.

My configuration is:
Mac OS X

Java 1.6

Maven 2.1

cargo-maven2-plugin 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT

Servlets spec 2.5 (web.xml)

Comment: Do the web.xml's from both WAR's have the DOCTYPE declaration? If not, try adding it to both and re-try.

Answer (score 0):

We had issues using `cargo uberwar` feature since we not only had common xml files, but also property files.

We overcame the issue (albeit in an ugly way) using [war overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html).   We ensured that the master war file had the superset of configurations that we wanted in the application.